# Returning the number of times the character at the start of the string occurs

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function length_char c string (that uses recursion) that takes a character c and a string string and returns the number of times that c occurs at the start of string.

So length char 'a' "aaabaa" should return 3, and length char 'c' "cbcac" should return 1.

I have tried this so far:

`length_char :: String -> Char -> Int`

`length_char str character = length $ filter (== character) str`

But am getting this error

```
    • In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘str’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘filter (== character) str’
      In the expression: length $ filter (== character) str
   |
   | length_char str character = length $ filter (== character) str
```

How do I do this where I use functions using recursion wherever possible and not use any library functions except head and tail.
I am also trying not to use list comprehension.

For example +, ++, &&, and : are all allowed, but `min` and `max` are not. • if expressions, let expressions, where syntax. • List ranges. • Pattern matching. The only things that I don't want to use are calling named library functions except for head and tail, and list comprehensions.

Comment: Are you sure you did not define `filter` somewhere yourself?

Comment: That's only part of the error message, indicating *where* the error occurred, not *what* the error actually was.

Comment: Please do not deleted answered questions!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of list-processing functions that you implement with recursion will cover two cases: (1) the empty list `[]` and (2) the non-empty list `(x:xs)` with `x` the first item of the list, and `xs` the remaining items.

You thus can try to implement this with:

```
length_char :: String -> Char -> Int
length_char [] _ = …
length_char (x:xs) y
    | … = …
    | otherwise = …
```

Here `x` is thus the first character, and `y` is the character we want to count. The conditions after the pipe character (`|`) are "guards" and should be boolean expressions. I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.